# Why can I not connect to my database?

Tags: java

I have the following code:

```
package connectivity;

import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class Connectivity {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
       cls o=new cls();
       try{
            Statement s=o.getct();
             ResultSet rs;

            rs=s.executeQuery("select * from REGISTRATION1");
           while(rs.next()){
                String st=rs.getString("FACULTY_ID");
                String st2=rs.getString("STUDENT_ID");


             }

        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```

The output is:

```
java.sql.SQLException:
[Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver]Invalid Descriptor Index"
```

Why?

Comment: Please don't shout - there's no need to use all those capitals

Comment: What's this `cls` class?

Comment: possible duplicate of [java.sql.SQLException:\[Microsoft\]\[ODBC Driver Manager\] Invalid descriptor index](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6361340/java-sql-sqlexceptionmicrosoftodbc-driver-manager-invalid-descriptor-in)

Answer (score 0):

Please explain connection statement in method getct()??
Make sure you have added
mysql-connector-java-xyz-bin jar file in your library.
The following code may be helpful:

```
   public static void main(String[] args) {
        Connection conn = null;
        Statement stmt = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;

        try {

            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
            System.out.println("Driver Setup");

        String connectionUrl = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db";
            String connectionUser = "root";
            String connectionPassword = "";//password if any
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl, connectionUser, connectionPassword);
            System.out.println("Connection setup");
            stmt = (Statement) conn.createStatement();
            rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM table_name");
            while (rs.next()) {
                String col1 = rs.getString("column1name");
                String col2 = rs.getString("column2name");

                System.out.println("First Value"+col1+"Second Value"+col2);
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like FACULTY_ID or STUDENT_ID is not there. Please check the names of columns in ResultSet or try reading by index.